# Can't get babel to compile string literal type with interpolation on typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I have a react application using typescript and I need to create types using literal string types with interpolation:

```js
class ExampleClass {
    product_id!: number;
    product_name!: string;
}

export type HeaderClassNames<N extends string> = `theader_${Lowercase<N>}`;

type HeaderClasses = HeaderClassNames<keyof ExampleClass>;
```

"HeaderClasses" produces:

```js
type HeaderClasses = "theader_product_id" | "theader_product_name"
```

This works fine by the tsc, but when babel transpiles, it doesn't recognize the template:

```js
Unexpected token (8:72)

   6 | 
   7 | export type TableHeaderConfig<Keys extends string> = Record<Keys, TableHeaderColumn>;
>  8 | export type HeaderClassNames<N extends string> = `theader_${Lowercase<N>}`;
     |                                                                         ^
   9 | export type ColumnClassNames<N extends string> = `column_${Lowercase<N>}`;
  10 |
```

Babel [said](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/10/15/7.12.0) it started supporting this feature, but I install and reinstall babel/core and even tried babel/parser manually (where the commit was made) but nothing changes.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: How about ``Lowercase<`theader_${N}`>`` instead?

Comment: @kaya3, thanks for commenting. I got a "Template literal types cannot have any substitution"

Comment: In that case, perhaps a helper type like ``Concat<A extends string, B extends string> = `${A}${B}`;`` and then ``type HeaderClassName<N extends string> = Concat<'theader_', Lowercase<N>>;`` will work?

Comment: It did not, no interpolation is working :/

Comment: Are you sure you're on a recent version of Babel that supports this?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I found out that the babel version being used was the one at the react-app-rewired and react-scripts packages. After some hours your head just doesn't work anymore.

I updated them and everything worked.

Thanks to everyone that spend a minute trying to help.